# How to properly use UTF-8-encoded data from Schema inside Catalyst app?

Tags: perl, utf-8, catalyst, dbix-class

Data defined inside Catalyst app or in templates has correct encoding and is diplayed well, but from database everything non-`Latin1` is converted to `?`. I suppose problem should be in model class, which is such:

```
use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->config(
 schema_class => 'vhinnad::Schema::DB',

 connect_info => {
     dsn => 'dbi:mysql:test',
     user => 'user',
     password => 'password',
     {
         AutoCommit        => 1,
         RaiseError        => 1,
         mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
     },
     'on_connect_do' => [
             'SET NAMES utf8',
     ],      
     }
);

1;
```

I see no flaws here, but something must be wrong. I used my schema also with test scripts and data was well encoded and output was correct, but inside Catalyst app i did not get encoding right. Where may be the problem?

**EDIT**

For future reference i put solution here: i mixed in connect info old and new style.

Old style is like `(dsn, username, passw, hashref_options, hashref_other options)`

New style is `(dsn => dsn, username => username, etc)`, so right is to use:

```
 connect_info => {
     dsn               => 'dbi:mysql:test',
     user              => 'user',
     password          => 'password',
     AutoCommit        => 1,
     RaiseError        => 1,
     mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
     on_connect_do     => [
             'SET NAMES utf8',
     ],      
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a typical Catalyst setup with Catalyst::View::TT and Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema you'll need several things for UTF-8 to work:

- add Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode::Encoding to your Catalyst app
- add `encoding => 'UTF-8'` to your app config
- add `ENCODING => 'utf-8'` to your TT view config
- add `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` to the `<head>` section of your html to satisfy old IEs which don't care about the `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` http header set by Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode::Encoding
- make sure your text editor saves your templates in UTF-8 if they include non ASCII characters
- configure your DBIC model according to [DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Using Unicode](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Using-Unicode)
- if you use Catalyst::Authentication::Store::LDAP configure your LDAP stores to return UTF-8 by adding `ldap_server_options => { raw => 'dn' }`

According to [Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema#connect_info](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema#connect_info):

*The old arrayref style with hashrefs for DBI then DBIx::Class options is also supported.*

But you are already using the 'new' style so you shouldn't nest the dbi attributes:

```
connect_info => {
     dsn               => 'dbi:mysql:test',
     user              => 'user',
     password          => 'password',
     AutoCommit        => 1,
     RaiseError        => 1,
     mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
     on_connect_do     => [
         'SET NAMES utf8',
     ],      
}
```

Comment: You can skip the Unicode::Encoding plug-in since Catalyst 5.90040; the plug-in is now included within Catalyst's core.

Answer (score 1):

This advice assumes you have fairly up to date versions of [DBIC](https://www.metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) and [Catalyst](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Catalyst).

- This is not necessary: `on_connect_do => [ 'SET NAMES utf8' ]`
- Ensure the table|column charsets are UTF-8 in your DB. You can achieve things that sometimes look right even when parts are broken. The DB must be saving the character data as UTF-8 if you expect the entire chain to work.
- Ensure you're using and configuring [Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode::Encoding](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Plugin::Unicode::Encoding) in your Catalyst app. It did have serious-ish bugs in the not too distant past so get the newest.

Comment: I have freshly installed most recent DBIC and Catalyst. I started from point you mentioned but when it did not worked i added `'SET NAMES utf8'` too. All databases i use have proper UTF-8 encoded data for years. I have enabled `Unicode::Encoding` plugin too.

Comment: So, if you do `show create table TableName` you see something like
`CHARSET=utf8` and *not* `Latin-1`, right? And you have something like
`__PACKAGE__->config( encoding => "UTF-8" )` somewhere in your app?

Comment: Yes, for both questions. Like i said: every UTF-8 string defined inside app comes out like it supposed to. And so is all right with schemas when i use them with some other scripts. But together i can't get them work.

Comment: If you use Template::Toolkit and Catalyst::View::TT you have to configure `ENCODING => 'utf-8',` in your view class . Furthermore you should put `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in your html head.

Comment: Well, there is some disconnect somewhere then or perhaps you have ancillary config/code biting you someplace? That setup does work as advertised. You're not using any deprecated stuff like the UTF8-columns DBIC thing? Your DBD is reasonably current? You aren't writing your own HTTP headers? Can you present a minimal MyApp style version that shows the problem? (Oh, just saw @abraxxa's comment++, good thing to try.)

Comment: @abraxxa: all this is also in place and if i define any complex UTF-8 string manually inside app, it is shown like a charm. But i left TT away from my question, because i have problem with pure JSON output, without templates involved. And i checked: JSON response has proper encoding in headers too

Comment: @w.k, Ah, now it becomes more clear. The Unicode::Encoding plugin doesn't operate on JSON (this is a known/debated issue). You'll have to do a bit more on your own. Give some details about your JSON view/generation and I (later) or someone (sooner) will help you.

Comment: @Ashley: No, i am not using UTF8-columns. DBD::mysql is 4.020. I am not writing HTTP-headers (and not-DB strings are OK). Showing all the app seemed a bit complex, but i think how to put it together.